# After performing an action,how to delay the starting of a new action?

Tags: android

I have a variable and I have set it to 3. every time when button is clicked it is          decremented and required action is performed. when it reaches 0 i want action should be display on the screen for a while and then it moves to new activity.

But problem is when it reaches 0 it does not hold for a while for the user to see the what action is performed it simply jumps to next page ...
is there any way to do this?

the code I'm using is:

```
if(ch==0)
{
try {

        Thread.sleep(15*1000);
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.quizproject.Menu"));
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

after using this code,the variable reaches 0 , it doesn't finishes the previous action rather pause then move to the next activity.

Any possible solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want the thread to sleep? You will look up the main thread and the user will not go to the Intent as the thread(sleep) is before the Intent.

That's why.

so:

```
while (ch <=0) {
Intent i = new Intent (this, menu.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: i am making an application the problem i m getting is i want to wait before starting a next action in the same activity....i making a quiz after the user selects an option i want to wait for a second to display the answer and then next ques arives..... but user is not able to see the answer immediately it moves to next question... so how to create a delay for the next question to arives...

Comment: Just display a progression bar with Async? I wouldn't recommend waiting though, you could force the user to hold down the back button an then progress onto the next Q. As always, if you feel my answer has been informative, hit the tick by my answer.

Comment: i use dis n its working .... creating a 2 sec delay . 

Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
          my_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.defaultcard); 
     } 
}, 2000); 


thank u for the advice

Comment: Okay, if my question helped you in any way, hit the huge tick.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class that extends Thread,for example `MyThread`:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    SampleActivity sampleActivity;

    public MyThread(SampleActivity sampleActivity){
        this.sampleActivity = sampleActivity;
    }



        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(15*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(this.sampleActivity, Asleep.class);
            sampleActivity.startActivity(i);
        }

}
```

**Edit**:
Then use it when you want start Activity,here `sampleActivity` is first Activity(first question) and `Asleep` is Activity that appears after 15 seconds(second question).So for example in click listener of a button in `sampleActivity` do like this:

```
MyThread mt = new MyThread(this);
mt.start();
```

Comment: i am making an application the problem i m getting is i want to wait before starting a next action in the same activity....i making a quiz after the user selects an option i want to wait for a second to display the answer and then next ques arives..... but user is not able to see the answer immediately it moves to next question... so how to create a delay for the next question to arives...

Comment: i use dis n its working .... creating a 2 sec delay . 

Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
          my_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.defaultcard); 
     } 
}, 2000); 


thank u ol for the advice